# Mongoose partial validations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema for mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Person = new Schema({
first_name: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
last_name: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
dob: {
    type: Date
},
phone: {
    type: String
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
address: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
city: {
    type: String
},
state: {
    type: String
},
zipCode: {
    type: Number
}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Person", Person);
```

My App user needs to fill 2 forms for this information. Half information like first_name,last_name,dob,phone will be in first form. I have to save this info first and then move to second form and on second form I have email,address,city,state,zipcode.

But when I save first form. It will give me Error because Email is required and which is on second form.

So How can I validate some fields which are in object using mongoose?

Or is there any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function on the required field in order to test if the first_name field is not empty, otherwise, the email field should not be required.

Something like this:

```
const Person = new Schema({
first_name: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
last_name: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
dob: {
    type: Date
},
phone: {
    type: String
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: () => this.first_name != null
},
address: {
    type: String,
    required: () => this.first_name != null
},
city: {
    type: String
},
state: {
    type: String
},
zipCode: {
    type: Number
}
});
```

[Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required)

Comment: Thanks this answer sounds very good. But what if one field is an array of sub documents and I want to perform `required: () => this.this subdocument[current index].other field of this subdocuments != null` How do I do that?